# use c# library in f#

Tags: c#, f#, libraries, tws

I am trying to connect to Interactive Brokers via their C# API.
As an exercise, I am trying to develop my client in F#.

This is what I have done:

1. I have imported the CSharpAPI project in Visual Studio. CSharpAPI defines the IBApi namespace
2. I have created a new F# project in the solution. The project will host my implementation
3. I created a new module in a .fs file as below:

   ```
   open IBApi

   module ibConnectivity =

      type IBclient =
          interface EWrapper with
          member this.connectionClosed() = printfn "connection has been closed"
          member this.currentTime time = printfn "server time: %i" time
   ....
   ```

I get the following error message:

> Error 1   Files in libraries or multiple-file applications must begin
>   with a namespace or module declaration, e.g. 'namespace
>   SomeNamespace.SubNamespace' or 'module SomeNamespace.SomeModule'

I have googled around for a solution. I am a complete noob.
Some posts refer to F# file order, but in this case I am working with a C# library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that your file must start with a `namespace` or `module` declaration. Like this:

```
module ibConnectivity

open IBApi

type IBclient =
    interface EWrapper with
    member this.connectionClosed() = printfn "connection has been closed"
    member this.currentTime time = printfn "server time: %i" time
```

The syntax `module Name = <indented declarations>` is used to declare sub-modules within the module or namespace declared at the top of the file.